# How to find sum of 2 different classes of tr , without counting all tr rows with no class

Tags: jquery

I am currently using the following script to determine how many table rows are in each table , then appending the data based on # of table rows returned. These tables are dynamically created and added to the site , and I had thought they always had 3 tr's that were present regardless even when no other data was populated. However I just found out that to be incorrect, so now this script needs tweaked a bit.

So how can i edit this line here

```
if($(this).find("tr").length !== +RequiredStarters &&
```

to find the sum of tr.oddtablerow and tr.eventablerow , instead of every tr  ?

```
var RequiredStarters = 9;   // ENTER THE NUMBER OF STARTERS YOUR LEAGUE REQUIRES

$(document).ready(function () {
  $.get('myurl', function (data) {
    $(data).find('td.two_column_layout .report').each(function(index, element){
      if($(this).find("tr").length !== +RequiredStarters + 3 && $(this).attr("id") !== "InvalidLineup"){
        var target = $("#InvalidLineup").find("tbody");
        $(this).find("span a").each(function(){
            target.append("<tr><td class='lineupalert'>" + $(this)[0].outerHTML + "<a class='lineuplink' href='#'>Submit Valid Lineup</a></td></tr>");
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Here is a html example , I now need to count the tr.oddtablerow and tr.eventable rows.

```
<table>
 <caption><span><a></a></span></caption>
  <tbody>
    <tr></tr>
    <tr class="oddtablerow"></tr>
    <tr class="eventablerow</tr>
    <tr class="oddtablerow"></tr>
    <tr class="eventablerow</tr>
    <tr class="oddtablerow"></tr>
    <tr class="eventablerow</tr>
    <tr class="oddtablerow"></tr>
    <tr class="eventablerow</tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xq1k33nh/

Comment: perfect , thanks , quite simple :)  thx !

Comment: See my answer, I post another simple way to do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Converting my comment in answer, use this:

```
$('tr.oddtablerow, tr.eventablerow').length
```

Or better, this:

```
$('tr[class]').length
```

FIDDLE1: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xq1k33nh/

FIDDLE2: https://jsfiddle.net/lmgonzalves/xq1k33nh/1/